# Orthogonal trajectories . eliminating parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonal-polynomials

Find the orthogonal trajectories of
$${x^{2} \over a^{2}} + {y^{2} \over a^{2}+t}= 1\,,\qquad
t\quad \mbox{is a parameter}
$$

I've tried eliminating $t$ and its given me a complicated looking equation. Surely I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving a try here. Implicit diff gives: $y' = - \frac{x(a^2+t)}{ya^2}$ For orthogonal trajectories, take opposite reciprocal to get $y' = \frac{ya^2}{x(a^2+t)}$ By seperation of variables you get $\frac{y'}{ya^2}=\frac{1}{x(a^2+t)}$ Anti deriving both sides gives $\frac{ln|y|}{a^2} = \frac{ln|x|}{a^2+t}+C$ From which it becomes algebra to solve for y if you wish. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Luckily I found a 'detailed' answer here : http://books.google.co.in/books?id=fxNjdUVeY4IC&pg=SA3-PA6&lpg=SA3-PA6&dq=x2+%2By2+%2B2gx%2Bc%3D0+orthogonal+trajectories&source=bl&ots=J7-wB2Iln1&sig=E15515lDrhPlj8tJPB4yaFgeT9U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=izaeUrTKI4SSrgfLyoCYAQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=x2%20%2By2%20%2B2gx%2Bc%3D0%20orthogonal%20traject